# Remove image link

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck in one of unique issue.

I was looking for a macro that will help to insert an image based on cell value.

I got the macro on the internet and modified it as per my requirement, this macro is working exactly the way I want however when I change or delete the image folder all the images are going vanished.

I tried to remove a link from an image but not succeeded, could you please help me understand what went wrong and how I can remove the link from the folder.

You may suggest another code also which will solve my problem.

```
    Sub InsertPictures()


    Const fPath = "C:\Desktop\Final snap as 0n 28 Jun\"

    Dim cel As Range, picPath As String, shp As Shape
'insert imagess
    For Each cel In Range("M4", Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        On Error Resume Next
        picPath = fPath & "\" & cel.Value & ".jpg"
        If Not Dir(picPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
            With cel.Parent.Pictures.Insert(picPath, LinkToFile = False)
                With .ShapeRange
                    .LinkToFile = msoFalse
                    .savewithdocument = msoCTrue
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                    .LinkToFile = False
                    .savewithdocument = True
                    .LockAspectRatio = False
                    .Width = 100
                    .Height = 100
                End With
                .Left = cel.Offset(, 1).Left
                .Top = cel.Offset(, 1).Top
            End With
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to insert the images rather than linking them:

```
    Sub Import_Picture()

Dim PicFilePath As String       'Directory of file
Dim InsertionRange As Range     'Range containing image directories
Dim Cel As Range                'Active Cell
Dim ERRORCNT As Integer         'Count directory errors

    ' >>> Edit this section to mach your
Set InsertionRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & _
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each Cel In InsertionRange              'Cycle cells
        PicFilePath = Cel.Value                 'Store directory
        If Dir(PicFilePath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then 'Check file exists
            With Application.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicFilePath)   'Add picture
                With .ShapeRange                '
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue  'Lock Aspect Ratio
                    .Height = Cel.Height        'Resize height to that of containing cell
                End With                        '
                .Left = Cel.Left                'Move to cell column
                .Top = Cel.Top                  'Move to cell row
            End With
        Else
            ' >>> Error Handling:
            Debug.Print "Unable to use path at " & _
                Cel.Address & " ->>> " & Cel.Value
            ERRORCNT = ERRORCNT + 1
        End If
    Next Cel
        
    If ERRORCNT > 0 Then
        ' >>> Error notification
        MsgBox "We were unable to find file directory for " & _
            ERRORCNT & " picture(s), see immediate window for more details", _
            vbOKOnly, "Directory Error"
    End If
        
End Sub
```

[image]